# Jquery Ajax not returning any response in the success body

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have tried all possible ways to get the result in my jquery ajax success body but i am failed. I dont find where I am wrong. I have already added the jquery library but still no result forIf someone guide me in my code will be a great help and will save my day.

my jquery ajax code is as follows:

i am calling a function on click of a button.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Farm Game</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="farm_game" method="POST">
<button type="button" name="feed" id="feed" onclick="PerformGame();">Feed</button>
</form>

 <script>
   function PerformGame()
   {
    
    var vars = "data sent to php file";
    $.ajax({
     url: 'perform_game.php',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {'send_data': vars},
     dataType: 'json',
                    
                    sucess: function(data) {
                        
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
   }

 
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and, my php code as follows:

```
<?php
```

$ajaxRes = $_POST['send_data'];

echo json_encode($ajaxRes);
?>

I dont find where i am doing wrong. Please help me !

Comment: If that code is exactly what you're using, part of the problem could be that your `success` case is spelled incorrectly as `sucess`

Comment: Hey Ryan, Thanks for you comment. I think I got my result. Thanks for saving my day.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is it, but in the ajax definition you spelled `sucess` wrong. It should be `success`.

Comment: Vote to close as a typo, not an answer